# php/mysql - access denied despite correct data

Tags: php, mysql-error-1045

i'm having a very strange problem:
i've set up a server, defined a db-password, installed phpmyadmin which is working.
but when trying to run a php-script which opens a database, i'm getting this error:

Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in D:\Web\database.php on line 13

i've used exact the same data as in my config.inc.php for phpmyadmin.
i already checked the root-user-rights and did reset the password inside phpmyadmin, didn't help.

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution by myself - i forgot that i'm using a different portnumber .. :/

Comment: You might consider deleting your question and answer then, unless you think that they could potentially useful to someone else.